# Get names of authors who have edited a post

Tags: posts, front-end

How can I call the usernames of people that have edited a post?

I know I can use `get_the_modified_time` to display the time the post was last modified, is the same possible with the list of users that edited it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The WordPress function [**`get_the_modified_author()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_modified_author) will give you the 
author who last edited the current post.

But if you want to list all the users that have edit the current post, you could try:

```
function get_the_modified_authors_wpse_99226(){
    global $wpdb;
    $authors = array();
    $results = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT post_author FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE (post_type = '%s' AND ID = %d) OR (post_type = 'revision' AND post_parent = %d) GROUP BY post_author", get_post_type( get_the_ID() ), get_the_ID(), get_the_ID() ) );
    foreach($results as $row){
          $authors[] =  get_the_author_meta('display_name', $row->post_author );
    }
    return implode(", ", $authors);
}
```

This function will give you a distinct comma seperated list of the users that have edit the current post (i.e. their display name). This should also work with custom post types.

Comment: excellent thank you so much! all I need to do now is wrap this in some sort of 'if post has been edited'. Thanks! :)

Comment: to do this I used this code

'<?php $u_time = get_the_time(‘U’);
$u_modified_time = get_the_modified_time(‘U’); if ($u_time !== $u_modified_time) {
echo get_the_modified_authors_wpse_99226(); }else echo(“Never Updated.”);?>'

Comment: ok great, thanks for sharing your solution (though this would be better served as a new question). Please mark the question as accepted if it solved your problems, thanks